# IE8 JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm working on this website: [link](http://semmelweis-bp.sulinet.hu/)

Everything works in the modern browsers, but in IE8 if I click on a plus sign in the left menu, I get an error.

The error is in the 52. line of this js: [js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60873668/mod_accordeonck.js)

```
content = $(link).parent();
```

Error is

```
Object doesn't support property or method
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method

Comment: Please post the portion of your JS that demonstrates the error, we're not going to try to examine your whole web page.

Comment: content = $(link).parent();

Comment: Maybe the link you click on doesn't have a parent? Do a `console.log`  on `link` and see what you get

Comment: Right off the bat: which version of jQuery are you using? Remember: versions 2.0+ do _not_ support versions of IE less than 9. The error message you're posting suggests that it's bubbling up from inside jQuery itself and the only thing I can think of is that it's using native DOM APIs which are unavailable in "old IE".

Comment: https://github.com/wailqill/jquery-placeholder/pull/3

Comment: @founddrama He's using 1.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From seeing your script,

```
togglemenu($(this));

function togglemenu(link){
                content = $(link).parent();
                ...
                ...
}
```

you can directly have

```
content = link.parent();
```

Comment: If you call jQuery on a jQuery object, it just returns it. There's no harm in the extra wrapping, except a little performance overhead.

Comment: Maybe, at 2.7k rep, you could finally reveal us your identity, fellow stranger, 1671639th of those who came here and spoke?

Comment: @JanDvorak:500 answers vs 0 question asked...RESPECT!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well `content` is not defined anywhere that I can see, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-:

```
$(link).closest('your closest parent')
```

Documentation=http://api.jquery.com/closest/